# Clauses in (lambda)prolog starting with a cut

Tags: prolog, logic-programming, prolog-cut, lambda-prolog

I am reading the paper [Implementing Type Theory in Higher Order Constraint Logic Programming](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01410567v2), and on p7 I see the following lambda-prolog code:

```
% KAM-like rules in CPS style
whd1 (app M N) S Ks Kf :- !, Ks [] M [N|S].
whd1 (lam T F1) [N|NS] Ks Kf :- !, pi x \ val x T N NF => Ks [x] (F1 x) NS.
whd1 X S Ks Kf :- !, val X _ N NF, if (var NF) (whd_unwind N NF), Ks [] NF S.
whd1 X S Ks Kf :- Kf.
```

I am confused about the position of the cut `!` in the third clause.  My understanding of a cut is that it always succeeds, but prevents backtracking past that success, and in particular causes subsequent clauses for the same predicate to be ignored.  In particular, a cut that comes *first* in a clause should mean that as soon as head unification with that clause succeeds, all later clauses are ignored.

With this in mind, the cuts that begin the first and second clauses above make sense to me: they say that if the term being reduced is an `app` or a `lam`, then only one rule can apply to it.  But it looks to me as though the head of the third clause is fully general -- all the arguments are distinct variables -- so it can't fail to unify.  Therefore, it seems to me that the cut that begins the third clause would *always* be invoked, and therefore the fourth clause would *never* be reached.  I would have expected the third clause to be written something like

```
whd1 X S Ks Kf :- val X _ N NF, !, if (var NF) (whd_unwind N NF), Ks [] NF S.
```

so that it would apply only to what they call "val-bound variables"; the cut would then indicate that if `X` is such a variable, only this clause applies, while if `X` isn't such a variable then we would be able to backtrack and try the fourth clause.

However, my understanding of cut is very rudimentary, so I expect I am missing something.  Can someone explain?

Comment: I don't know the answer but your understanding of cut seems correct for normal Prolog but the code you note is not normal Prolog, the paper notes it is λProlog. As the comment notes it is, `CPS style` which could also change the semantics of the code. Also consider if there is a meta interpreter or something that is changing the execution strategy of the code. Just because you may think of it as `or` clauses, they may be `and` clauses or something else. In other words don't assume anything and start again from scratch in trying to understand the code, even `!` may not be a cut.

Comment: The statement in the paper that gets my attention related to your question is `we code the reduction machine in Continuation Passing Style (CPS). The
whd1 predicate relates the head and stack of the machine together with two continuations
Ks (for success) and Kf (for failure).` Notice that the first three clauses end with `Ks _ _ _` while the last clause ends with `Kf`. As I don't know λProlog there is not much more I can add.

Comment: @GuyCoder I'm pretty sure that `!` is also a cut in lambda-prolog.  I don't think "CPS style" means anything different about the semantics of the code, it just means that they've chosen to write the function in a particular way, with the arguments `Ks` and `Kf` being predicates that function like "continuations" -- that's why all the clauses end by calling one or the other of them instead of simply "returning a value" (in the appropriate prology sense).